# Android App Crashing When Activity Recreates

Tags: android, android-activity, recreate

In my application , there is an activity in which data is saved in java databean. Data is being saved depending on user selection. Now I pause and then stop my application by minimizing it. Now in background I open 18-20 applications . In the process when I open other application, Android Clears out the instance of databean object . And then i open the application , it opens through same activity as mentioned and application crahes.

Comment: try using sharedpreferences to store persistent data

Comment: Its ton of Data and its also not serializale

Comment: try sqlite database to handle lots of data.

Comment: That's all very interesting. Perhaps you wanted to actually [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe post some code or logcat for people to help you?